# raspberry pi 3 (Ubuntu Mate) to install the libts-dev

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Sorry, I'm a newbie to the raspberry pi3, I try to install a package name

"libts-dev" using the command

sudo apt-get install libts-dev

but the linux returns

unable to locate package libts-dev

hope anyone can help me... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run `sudo apt-get update` to get a newer list of packages that are available. Then try to run the `sudo apt-get install libts-dev` command again.